# How to join multiple tables using join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am trying to join multiple tables and getting data. But I am getting duplicate data. How can I resolve this? Any help.

```
select reliability.id,
reliability.type, 
header_id, 
header_name, 
parents.parent, 
namestates.namestate,
probabilities.probabilities
from reliability 

inner join headers
on reliability.id = headers.reliability_id 

inner join parents
on parents.reliability_id = reliability.id 

inner join definitions
on definitions.reliability_id = reliability.id

inner join namestates
on namestates.definition_id = definitions.id

inner join probabilities
on probabilities.definition_id = definitions.id

group by namestates.namestate,
probabilities.probabilities;
```

[image]

Comment: On those 4 rows, all I see is different data, no duplicates. Which result are you expecting?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. With most DBMSs your SQL would fail: if you have a GROUP BY then all the columns in your SELECT either need to be in the GROUP BY or be aggregated

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? (I see no aggregate functions.)

Comment: In addition to the comments above, you can check each table if the "id" used for joining (or join keys) have unique value and has 1:1 relationship.

Comment: @JohanB , in the probabilities column we are getting duplicate values.

Comment: Duplicate data normally refers the whole row, not a specific column, so in that sense you don’t have duplicate data as the namestate values differ between rows. If you want to eliminate one of these rows just then just filter on the appropriate namestate value in a WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Please use left join..

```
select reliability.id,
reliability.type, 
header_id, 
header_name, 
parents.parent, 
namestates.namestate,
probabilities.probabilities
from reliability 

left join headers on reliability.id = headers.reliability_id 

left join parents on parents.reliability_id = reliability.id 

left join definitions on definitions.reliability_id = reliability.id

left join namestates on namestates.definition_id = definitions.id

left join probabilities on probabilities.definition_id = definitions.id

group by namestates.namestate, probabilities.probabilities;
```